# Lista de usuários online

Tags: php

Eu preciso criar uma lista de usuários online no momento, ou até 20 minutos atrás.
Sendo que a tabela com os dados dos usuários se chama 'Usuário', e a tabela que tem os acessos destes usuários se chama 'Core.logs'.

Não faço idéia de como fazer isso! Alguém pode ao menos me dar uma dica?

Comment: O que são essas tabelas? Tabelas de banco de dados? Se sim, qual banco? Qual é a estrutura das tabelas? Se não, são arquivos de texto? Como estão organizados?

Comment: Sim,de banco de dados, Mysql. A estrutura das tabelas Table: usuario
Columns:
usuario_id int(11) AI PK 
usuario_tipo_id int(11) 
nome varchar(255) 
apelido varchar(255) 
email varchar(255) 
senha varchar(255) 
imagem varchar(255) 
sessao varchar(255) 
telefone varchar(45) 
cargo varchar(255) 
setor varchar(255) 
status int(1) 
api_key varchar(255) 

Table: core_logs
Columns:
core_logs_id int(11) AI PK 
usuario_id int(11) 
cliente_id int(11) 
referencia varchar(45) 
acao enum('C','R','U','D') 
sessao_alias varchar(255) 
metadata longtext 
data timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que deu pra entender, a `Core.logs` é uma tabela de auditoria.

O campo data provavelmente dever armazenar data das ações que foram realizadas pelos usuários.

Você pode pegar essa data e fazer uma verificação, onde as últimas ações dentre de 20 minutos você mostra os dados dos usuários em uma lista.

Comment: Mas como eu faria essa verificação?